# Type casting when working with nested data structures

Tags: haskell, nested, algebraic-data-types

I have the following data structures defined:

```
data Operator = Plus | Times | Minus deriving (Eq,Show)
data Variable = A | B | C deriving (Eq,Show)
newtype Const = D Numeral deriving (Eq,Show)
data CVO = Const | Variable | Operator deriving (Eq,Show)
type Expr = [CVO]
```

I have defined the following function:

```
eval2 :: Expr -> Integer
eval2 x = helper x
```

I would like to check if an element of the CVO list (Expr) is either an instance of Const, Variable or Operator (this works) and I would like to implement varying code for the specific type of the instance (e.g. Plus, Times, Minus for Operator).

```
helper :: Expr -> Integer
helper [] = 2
helper (x:xs) 
    | x == Operator && x == Plus = 1
```

I cannot compare x to Plus, because it expects x to be of type CVO.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘CVO’ with actual type ‘Operator’
```

Is it somehow possible to cast x to be an instance of Operator in order to do the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value can't have two different types at the same time. If `x` is a `CVO` you can't use `==` to compare it to `Plus` which is an `Operator`.

At the moment the type `CVO` consists of three *constant values* called `Const`, `Variable` and `Operator`. I'm guessing you actually wanted it to contain values of the type `Const`, `Variable` or `Operator`. You do that by declaring arguments to the constructors.

```
data CVO = Const Const  -- a constructor whose name is Const and contains a value of type Const
         | Var Variable  -- a constructor named Var containing a Variable
         | Op Operator  -- a constructor named Op containing an Operator
```

A given value of type `CVO` must have been built from one of those three constructors, containing a value of the correct type. You can test which constructor was used to create the `CVO`, and simultaneously unpack the value, using *pattern matching*. Something like this:

```
helper :: Expr -> Integer
helper [] = 0
helper (Op o:xs)  -- because we matched Op, we know o :: Operator
    | o == Plus = 1
    | otherwise = 2
helper _ = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.